# Lucene full text joined with database criteria

Tags: java, sql, database, lucene

I have an app with case records stored in a Derby database, and am using Lucene to full-text index case notes and descriptions.  The full-text is relatively static, but some database fields can change daily on many records, to updating Lucene from the database is not a good option.

What I want to do is allow the user to do a full-text query along with some SQL criteria.  For example:  all cases that have the words "water" and "melon" (the full-text portion) that were edited in the last 2 days, and their "importance" flag is set to "medium" (the SQL portion).  (the full-text query could be much more complex, and similarly for the SQL portion).

This involves a "join" (actually "AND") of the full-text results with the DB results, I can either run a full-text search and check each record for DB criteria, or vice versa, depending on whether the full-text or the SQL criteria yield smaller number of records.  This is obviously a slow process.

Are there better/faster solutions?

Answer (score 0):

We have done something like this. We used a postgres database but as you said, returning all the matching ids from the database for checking on the index is too slow.

In our case, we only needed to update flags for a document. Fortunately, we could allow us to have a little bit expensive update operation on the database. So we decided to have a blob entry for each flag containing all matching document ids as serialized ArrayList or something alike. When searching, we just needed to retrieve one entry from the database which was fast enough for a million of ids.